# C# RegEx on address doen't work properly

Tags: c#, regex

So I need the address out of a string, but I have different cases, so I covered many, but now I can't get working this case:

Original String:

> HRB 145942: playloop UG (haftungsbeschränkt), Hamburg, **Eimsbütteler Chaussee 57, c/o Jan Sorgenfrei**, 20259 Hamburg. Gesellschaft mit beschr
>
> HRB 145941: TBE-Ehrbare Rebellen GmbH, Hamburg, **Friedrich-Ebert-Damm 111**, 22047 Hamburg. Gesellschaft mit beschr
>
> HRB 145923: Lionheart Asset Management GmbH, München, **Trenknerweg 100 A, c/o Barthold Brümmer**, 22605 Hamburg. Gesellschaft mit beschr
>
> HRB 716239: CarboCode Germany GmbH, Konstanz, **Byk-Gulden-Straße 2, Gebäude F21**, 78467 Konstanz. Gesellschaft mit beschr

So I need "**Eimsbütteler Chaussee 57, c/o Jan Sorgenfrei**" and "**Friedrich-Ebert-Damm 111**" and "**Trenknerweg 100 A, c/o Barthold Brümmer**" and "**Byk-Gulden-Straße 2, Gebäude F21**"

Even just the address without the c/o would help me a lot
My RegEx is: `, \d{5}.+\.`

And my problem is, that it gets normal addresses like "Friedrich.." but in the "c/o" addresses it just takes like "c/o Jan Sorgenfrei" and missing the string before or it just takes the "Gebäude F21".

After getting the string from the RegEx I do the following to filter out some things:

```
stadt = stadt.Substring(0, stadt.LastIndexOf('.'));
stadt = new string(stadt.Where(c => c != '-' && (c < '0' || c > '9')).ToArray());
stadt = stadt.Substring(1);
```

Comment: Try `Regex.Match(s, @"\b([^,]+,[^,]+),\s*\d{5}").Groups[1].Value`.

Comment: If you need the cities, too, use `\b[^,]+,[^,]+,\s*\d{5}\s*\w*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that format always remains the same you *might* not need ReGex here.
Note that this will take the city part as well :

```
        var addressList = new[]
        {
            "HRB 145942: playloop UG (haftungsbeschränkt), Hamburg, Eimsbütteler Chaussee 57, c/o Jan Sorgenfrei, 20259 Hamburg. Gesellschaft mit beschr",
            "HRB 145941: TBE - Ehrbare Rebellen GmbH, Hamburg, Friedrich-Ebert - Damm 111, 22047 Hamburg.Gesellschaft mit beschr",
            "HRB 145923: Lionheart Asset Management GmbH, München, Trenknerweg 100 A, c / o Barthold Brümmer, 22605 Hamburg.Gesellschaft mit beschr",
            "HRB 716239: CarboCode Germany GmbH, Konstanz, Byk - Gulden - Straße 2, Gebäude F21, 78467 Konstanz.Gesellschaft mit beschr"
        };

        var addresses = addressList.Select(
            s =>
            {
                var secondIndexOfComma = s.IndexOf(',', s.IndexOf(',') + 1);
                return s.Substring(secondIndexOfComma + 2, s.LastIndexOf('.') - secondIndexOfComma - 2);
            });

        foreach (var address in addresses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(address);
        }
```

Output:

```
Eimsbütteler Chaussee 57, c/o Jan Sorgenfrei, 20259 Hamburg
Friedrich-Ebert - Damm 111, 22047 Hamburg
Trenknerweg 100 A, c / o Barthold Brümmer, 22605 Hamburg
Byk - Gulden - Straße 2, Gebäude F21, 78467 Konstanz
```

Comment: Nice, it works as I want. I just take a substring before the last comma, to cut of the ZIP and City. I think for another problem relating the RegEx of the whole thing (not address) I should make another question?

Comment: Yep, create a new question

Comment: Alright, but now I have a problem with your solution at this case:
`<br>HRB 215102: Chinesisches Zentrum, Hannover UG (haftungsbeschränkt), Hannover, Maschstraße 7, 30169 Hannover. Gesellschaft mit beschr`

It returns: `Hannover, Maschstraße 7, 30169 Hannover`

Comment: Even if you use regex you'd need a pattern that matches all records, and if there's some atypical record that doesn't match the pattern it'll be a problem